# Ported Android app denied: "process has stopped unexpectedly" (although tested on Dev Alpha)

Tags: blackberry-android

I have a ported Android game (packaged via Online Packager). The game runs fine on PlayBook (OS 2.0.1) and real Dev Alpha device (OS 10.0.9.388). However it was rejected when tested in AppWorld:
" ... testing your app on the BlackBerry Dev Alpha (OS version 10.0.9.1103). The
application fails to launch and displays the following error message "(process
xxxxxx) has stopped unexpectedly..."

Is there any difference (in terms of Android support) between both Dev Alpha OS builds? How can I get a log of the AppWorld testing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can contact the BlackBerry App World team directly for vendor support via the following portal.

Contact App World Vendor Support
https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8109

You can also re-test the application using the most recently released version of BlackBerry 10 developer software (10.0.09.1675).

Updating the BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha Device Software
https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/blackberry10devalpha/devalpha_update.html

Comment: Thanks. I just recompiled it once again and submitted it and it was approved.